# products not showing on anchor category

Tags: magento-1.9

Ive changed a category to be an anchor category, but the products beneath this category are not showing on the category in list view as expected. What am I missing? Other categories marked as anchor ARE showing products.

Comment: Did you reindex after the changes?

Comment: Yes, and flushed cache.

Comment: What do you mean by "products beneath this category"? The products in this category or the products in this category's subcategories?

Comment: Do you see the products if the category is not anchor?

Answer (score 0):

This Might be issue of below setting, please check below setting and let me know if you still face issue

goto

`catalog->category->click on your category->display setting->displaymode`

and change this setting to  `Products only` and then clear cache and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Pontikos, it was a reindex problem! Normally magento tells me when something needs to be reindexed. In this case when I checked the indexes they were all green so I hadn't actually reindex anything. But when I did a "select all" for the indexes and just did a reindex anyway, it worked. Thanks for your time everyone.